# Save Password behavior clarification of IE, Chrome, and FireFox

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, internet-explorer

My web application is written using MVC5 and C#.

I have 2 pages where a user can enter their username and password. One of them is the Request Account page, the other is the Login page.

I am seeing different behavior of the Save Password prompt across IE, Chrome and FireFox.

The URIs are:

```
/Account/RequestAccount
/Account/Login
```

**FIREFOX** - Prompts user to Save Password on either page. On submission of the Request Account form the user is offered to save the username/password. If the user opts to save the password FireFox will perform autocomplete when the user returns to the Login form. This behavior is desired and seems correct.

**IE & CHROME** - Neither of these browsers offer to save the username/password when the Request Account form is submitted. However both browsers offer to save username/password when the user submits the Login form.

Honestly, I don't see how IE or Chrome can make a distinction based on URI and I don't believe that they do. This leaves me with suspecting there may b something incorrect with my form fields except that they work fine on the Login page.

Both of my Login and Request Account pages use identical form field IDs (UserName and Password).

```
<input class="form-control valid" data-val="true" 
data-val-email="The Username field is not a valid e-mail address." 
data-val-required="The Username field is required." id="UserName" name="UserName"
type="email" value="" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">

<input class="form-control" data-val="true" 
data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password"
type="password">
```

My question, is there something specific that needs to be done in the Request Account page form fields to trigger the Save Password prompt like FireFox does? Or, does IE and Chrome dismiss the Request Account page as not being an actual login page (somehow)?

Answer (score 1):

Does adding the `autocomplete="on"` property helps?

IE11 will no longer support it though:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I didn't think of this, but just tried it and no, it doesn't cause IE to prompt to save password on the Reuest Account submission. :S